# Debugging Vim PlugIn Loading

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using MacVim on OSX 10.6 and I started getting a strange error message when I open certain files and directories with `vim` in the terminal. The `vim` command is just a symlink to the `mvim` script that comes with MacVim, and I am sure that I am running the MacVim binary, not the vim binary that ships with OSX.

The error meesage I get is `E73: tag stack empty`.

This only happens when I open things with `vim`. It doesn't happen when I use `mvim` and open them in the gui version. Is there a way to turn on debug output or something for vim so I can tell what line of code in which plugin is causing this?

-- additional information --

You can see the source of the mvim script, which launches MacVim from the command line, here: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/snapshot-61/src/MacVim/mvim.

I installed MacVim with homebrew. Here's where all the files live:

```
$ which mvim
/usr/local/bin/mvim
$ which vim
/Users/mattcampbell/bin/vim
$ ls -lh `which vim`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mattcampbell  staff    19B Aug 22 18:36 /Users/mattcampbell/bin/vim -> /usr/local/bin/mvim
```

Comment: Share the file where you did the symlink.

Answer (score 5):

`:help E73` suggests you are trying to use the tagstack.

`:scriptnames` will show you which scripts you have loaded. Look to see if there's anything unexpected there.

If that doesn't turn up anything useful, use:

```
set verbose=20
```

...in your `.vimrc`. This will give you a lot of information, so don't forget to reset it after you've fixed your issue.

Comment: This didn't end up helping as it was so verbose that I couldn't find the error in all the output. I ended up having to remove all my plugins and comment out everything in my .vimrc. I then added things back one by until I found the offending commands.